# Can't find my error. The program does not ignore the question and interfires with the while statement

Tags: c++

The program does not ignore the string question and interferes with the while statement. When I answer the first question I cannot answer the question "Would you like to ask another question? Answer Y/N:" because the program ends. I already put cin.ignore so I don't know why it is not ignoring the answer to the first question

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int rollDie();

int main()
{
    string question;
    char repeat;


    do
    {

        cout << "Hello, I am the magic 8-ball! Ask me a question and I will give you an answer" << endl;
        cout << "Your question: ";

        
        cin >> question;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << endl << endl;


        int roll = rollDie() % 5 + 1;

        if (roll == 5)
            cout << "Answer: It is certain " << endl;

        if (roll == 4)
            cout << "Answer: Reply hazy, Try Again " << endl;

        if (roll == 3)
            cout << "Answer: Don't count on it " << endl;

        if (roll == 2)
            cout << "Answer: Signs point to yes " << endl;

        if (roll == 1)
            cout << "Answer: My sources say no " << endl;


        cout << "Would you like to ask another question? Answer Y/N: ";
        cin >> repeat;

    } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');

    


    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int rollDie()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand();
}
```

Comment: OT: `srand(time(NULL));` should be called 1 time total not every time you want a random number.

Comment: `cin >> question;` Remember that this line reads up to the first whitespace character. You probably want to use std::getline() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `cin >> question`. This will only read to the next whitespace. If you type beyond that, other cin statments will read them.
Instead, use `std::getline()`:

```
std::getline(std::cin, question);
```